# Unsupported Media type, backend, Please guide me

Tags: python, backend, falconframework

I am trying to receive a pdf file by using falcon framework as Backend.
I am a beginner at backend and trying to understand what is happening. So summary, there are 2 classes. one of them, are my friends which are working.

this is the backend side code:

```
#this is my code
class VehiclePolicyResource(object):
    def on_post(self, req, resp, reg):
        local_path = create_local_path(req.url, req.content_type)
        with open(local_path, 'wb') as temp_file:
            body = req.stream.read()
            temp_file.write(body)
#this is my friend code
class VehicleOdometerResource(object):
    def on_post(self, req, resp, reg):
        local_path = create_local_path(req.url, req.content_type)
        with open(local_path, 'wb') as temp_file:
            body = req.stream.read()
            temp_file.write(body)
```

It is exactly the same and did not give the same answer and I add the route by doing this

`api.add_route('/v1/files/{reg}/policies',VehicleResourcesV1.VehiclePolicyResource())`

and by using this command in terminal :

`HTTP POST localhost:5000/v1/files/SJQ52883Y/policies@/Users/alfreddatui/Autoarmour/aa-atlas/static/asd.pdf`

it trying to get the file. But it keep saying, Unsupported media type.
WHILE the other code, receiving image, literally the same code as above, it works.

Any idea ?

Comment: sorry wrong command:
HTTP POST localhost:5000/v1/files/SJQ9957Y/policies @/Users/alfreddatui/Autoarmour/aa-atlas/static/asd.pdf

Comment: What is happening in `create_local_path`? Does it raise an exception when content type passed doesn't fit the bill

Comment: oops sorry, it make a string that point to a directory(which I want to save the file at)
this is the code:
```def create_local_path(url, content_type):
    image_type = url.split('/')[-1]
    ext = mimetypes.guess_extension(content_type)
    name = '{}/{}{}'.format(image_type, uuid.uuid4(), ext)
    return os.path.join('./temp/', name)
```

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: yes me too, looks fine, but not working :(

Comment: The error message is unsupported media type

Answer (score 3):

Falcon has out of the box support for requests with `Content-Type: application/json`.

For other content types, you need to provide a media handler for your request.

Here is an attempt at implementing a handler for requests of `Content-Type: application/pdf`.

```
import cStringIO
import mimetypes
import uuid
import os

import falcon
from falcon import media
from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser
from pdfminer.pdfdocument import PDFDocument

class Document(object):
    def __init__(self, document):
        self.document = document
    # implement media methods here

class PDFHandler(media.BaseHandler):
    def serialize(self, media):
        return media._parser.fp.getvalue()

    def deserialize(self, raw):
        fp = cStringIO.StringIO()
        fp.write(raw)
        try:
            return Document(
                PDFDocument(
                    PDFParser(fp)
                )
            )
        except ValueError as err:
            raise errors.HTTPBadRequest(
                'Invalid PDF',
                'Could not parse PDF body - {0}'.format(err)
            )
```

Update media handlers to support `Content-Type: application/pdf`.

```
extra_handlers = {
    'application/pdf': PDFHandler(),
}

app = falcon.API()
app.req_options.media_handlers.update(extra_handlers)
app.resp_options.media_handlers.update(extra_handlers)
```

Comment: Found this solution as very useful, Thanks alot. Need do few changes for python3.x.

Answer (score 0):

I got it, 
I just notice that Falcon by default will receive JSON file(please correct me if I am wrong)
So I need to make an exception for pdf and image file.

Comment: You are right about the default handler for request content types of `application/json`